# lesser metamagic rods on metamagiced spells

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items, metamagic

There was information somewhere that a lesser metamagic rod could be used on up to 3rd level spells that are under regular metamagic effects from the caster. Can anyone show me where this information is? I cant remember if it was a question, answer, form post. I just remember having read it. Came up in todays game and wanted to provide the information to the group.

So for example, a wizard could use a lesser metamagic rod of empower on a maximized fireball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Metamagic'd spells count as the slot used to cast them for metamagic rods.

The [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9r9w) on metamagic spells and the levels they count for states:

> #### Metamagic: At what spell level does the spell count for concentration DCs, magus spell recall, or a pearl of power?
>
> The spell counts as the level of the spell slot necessary to cast it.
>
> For example, an empowered burning hands uses a 3rd-level spell slot, counts as a 3rd-level spell for making concentration checks, counts as a 3rd-level spell for a magus's spell recall or a pearl of power.
>
> **In general, use the (normal, lower) spell level or the (higher) spell slot level, whichever is more of a disadvantage for the caster.** The advantages of the metamagic feat are spelled out in the Benefits section of the feat, and the increased spell slot level is a disadvantage.
>
> Heighten Spell is really the only metamagic feat that makes using a higher-level spell slot an advantage instead of a disadvantage.

Since it'd be less beneficial for a caster to have the spell count as a higher spell level when using a metamagic rod, they count as the higher level spell.

Comment: If you're looking for an online source for rules content in the core book, you can use the legacy document instead, since it's more tightly based on the books themselves. Here's the relevant page on rods, with the note from this answer present: http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/magicItems/rods.html

Comment: This does not directly answer if the metamagic rod can be used on a 3rd level fireball spell thats adjusted to a 6th level slot due to max. The spell is still technically a 3rd level spell but the slot is much higher.

Comment: @Fering oh sorry, I misread the question, I thought you were asking about metamagic rods in combination with the feats in general.

Comment: @Fering there, that should answer your question now, though it's the opposite of what you were thinking.